# how to give value from json with js

Tags: javascript, json

I have this JSON data

```
var testData = {text: '{"status":200}'};
```

And I am trying to receive the `status` with this code:

```
console.log(testData.text.status);
```

But it receives `undefined`

Can you tell me how to receive the status?

Comment: thank you, twice answer works fine! :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly json. You have object with json as property. You can do this:

```
testData.text = JSON.parse(testData.text);
testData.text.status;
```

Answer (score 1):

`testData.text` is a string. You will need to parse this string to JSON.

For example:

```
var myObj = JSON.parse(testData.text);
alert(myObj.status);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse